# Does Keystone Require Session configuration for option Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

Hi I've been running a keystone site on a sandbox database and my app_session collection is massive with all the expiration dates in the future. Only 3 users thus far. Only one has ever logged in. Does anyone know why this might be? I host on googles app builder. I have the session store set to mongo.

Edit, deleted app_session data but it's growing constantly.
Edit, in app_sessions database documents session property userId = null

Comment: You mean [KeystoneJS](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone) right?  A quick search of the project `package.json` yields `"express-session": "1.15.2",` as a dependency. So it would appear to be configured in.

Comment: yes, thank you keystonejs. The configuration specifies it can use connect-mongo to persist.

Comment: I'm pretty sure without actually looking that the "session store" would be generic and you can configure to whatever really. As for the connect-mongo bit, I'm sure there are documentation pieces that would point to a TTL index for session expiry. Again I'm not looking at this point, but it would make sense.